# html div container doesn't take height by the content inside

Tags: html, containers

Why `<div id = "container">` has height of 433px? I make this page http://www.elektroninescigaretes.ym.lt/ and when I instect an element it shows me div has only 433px and I want to make on footer All rights reserved (c) stuff, so I need div to have height of all page not only of the upper part.

```
//index file
<?php include ("template/header.php"); ?>
<div id = "home_content"></div>
<?php include ("template/footer.php"); ?>


//header file

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel = "stylesheet" href = "media/styles/style.css" media = "screen">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>el Cigarai</title>
</head>
<body class = "<?php 
$remove = array(".php", "/");
$url = $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'];
$current_file = str_replace($remove, "", $url);
 $current_page = explode('_', $current_file);
 echo $current_page[0];
?>">

<div id = "container">

//footer file

</div>
</body>
</html>

  /style file

#container{
position: relative;
margin: 0 auto;
width: 960px;
height: 100%;
}
#home_content{
position: absolute;
top: 294px;
right: 60px;
width: 960px;
height: 750px;
background-image: url('../images/woman.jpg');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: please : format your code, format your text, and ask a clear question

Comment: `#home_content` is out of the document flow because it has the attribute `position:absolute`.  if you remove that attribute, it allows the content to expand the parent container.  You will have to change how the site works, unfortunately, but you might be able to just set a fixed height.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a height of 100% set, this means if your content grows larger than the 100% represented by the viewport (or parent container), it will not grow.  Try using

```
min-height:100%
```

Comment: thank you i added min-height:100% but it didnt displayed all items on my list so i added padding-bottom and now is good :)

Answer (score 0):

Put this in your style:

```
html body{height: 100%;}
```